# The worst thing he can be called

Tags: grammar

Which one is the correct?

1. The worst thing he **can** be called is a coward.
2. The worst thing he **could** be called is a coward.

I think it's the second one because it's about possibility in the future; on the other hand, "can" might suit better in a general statement like: "In my culture, the worst thing one can be called is a coward."

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: Without knowing which meaning is required, either is possible. "Can" relates to present affairs and "could" has a greater element of the hypothetical or future.

Comment: Both are fine, and in practice would mostly be equivalent and interchangeable. Some people might claim a nuance of difference (in "immediacy"?), but offhand I can't think of any context where the choice would actually change the meaning in a noticeable way. Note that *The worst thing he **could** be called **was** a coward* really has a different meaning, and *The worst thing he **can** be called **was** a coward* is invalid.

Comment: *Idiomatically*, we're much more likely to use "conditional" ***could*** in such contexts, simply because the entire reason for framing such an utterance is *the speaker doesn't know what it is.* So he's *speculating* - as in *It **could be** true, but I don't know for sure*, where we never use ***can***.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.
"Can" refers to the present state of things.
"Could" refers to the most extreme possible future state.

That said, they are often used interchangeably.